# Angular: req.handle.writev is not a function , error when running Angular old application

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, http

I am running Angular application which is old:[angular/cli-1.4.5,node:10.13.0 and windows: win32 x64 ]. 
when I am serving my application , its compiling successfully , but the web serve get crashed and it saying this following error:"

Error:

```
 internal/stream_base_commons.js:62
 var err = req.handle.writev(req, chunks, allBuffers);"

 TypeError: req.handle.writev is not a function
            at writevGeneric (internal/stream_base_commons.js:62:24)
            at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:711:5)
            at Socket._writev (net.js:720:8)
            at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:408:12)
            at clearBuffer (_stream_writable.js:517:5)
            at Socket.Writable.uncork (_stream_writable.js:314:7)
            at connectionCorkNT (_http_outgoing.js:641:8)
            at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Is there any solution to resolve this error.

Comment: Having the same problem. Can't really pinpoint what is going on / how to fix it

Comment: @Mariusjp:    Hi , I use this command to solve my issue. Earlier I used different command to server my application and It didn't worked. later I used this one:     ng serve --ssl --live-reload=false to serve application , its worked with no issues. Exactly I don't know what's the reason.

Answer (score 0):

setting

> "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.8.9",

seems to help (originally it was 0.6.8 before I've tried updating node to 10 in my project). The webpack-dev-server which actually contains error is a @angular-devkit/build-angular's dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I've searched on node [crash with req.handle.writev](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/21665)

In my case I was using spdy lib for http2 request, just removed the lib and installed node 12.x.x LTS.